# Mybatis to return a string not List of String

Tags: ibatis, mybatis

I have a straight forward query like,

```
Select emp_Name from Employee where empID=123
```

How can i get the return as only `String` instead of `List<String>`, as here this query will return only one value.

Comment: You should provide information are you using mybatis (newer version with mappers) or ibatis. And are you using mappers at all.

Comment: I am using xml mappers only.

Comment: Than just set return type of your mapper interface to `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change return type of method in your mapper interface to `String`. This will return only value or `null` if there is no entry.

Comment: yes i tried with Only String, its returning the value, thanks @partlov, if it return multiple row will throw any error??? I need to check for if the query return multiple rows.. anyways thanks.

Comment: If query returns multiple rows it will throw Exception. You can try to see what is happening.